# org mode how to change color of list

Tags: colors, emacs, org-mode

```
1. one
2. two

+ one
+ two
```

I want to change color of `1.` `2.` and so on by
I searched lisp but it does't work

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'org-list-dt nil :background "#ff00ff")
```

Comment: `org-list-dt` is for description lists (`- item :: text`) not numbered lists. You could try using hi-lock-mode, specifying a regular expression that matches numbers at the start of the line.

Answer (score 2):

org-mode didn't provide dedicated face for bullets of plain list, you've to extend it yourself.

```lisp
(defface my-face-for-list-bullet
  '((t :background "red"))
  "Face for bluuet of plain list")

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 '(("^\\([0-9]+[.)]\\|\\+\\|\\-\\) " 1 'my-face-for-list-bullet))
 'append)
```

[image: demo]

Note that I only considered top level lists.